# Optimize SQL Query Inside a Loop: Load customers together with reviews

Tags: collection, performance, sql, review

In the product page i have a list of all reviews made by customers and I'm showing customer username, avatar and date with each review. The solution I'm using will result in a performance bottleneck. How can the code be improved?

```
<?php 
    $_items = $this->getReviewsCollection()->getItems();
    foreach ($_items as $_review): ?>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <?php
                    $customer_id = $_review->getCustomerId();
                    $customer_data = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
                    $avatarURL = "customer" . $customer_data->getMedmaAvatar();
                    $username = $customer_data->getUsername();
                    $shortdate = $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt(),'short');
                     ?>
            <div>content blablabla</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest would be to get all customers and load them:

```
$customerIds = Mage::getResourceModel('review/review_collection')
    ->getColumnValues('customer_id');
$customerCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $customerIds));
$customer_data = $customerCollection->getItemById($_review->getCustomerId());
```